# Why do I get binary numbers instead of correlation values in GGally::ggpairs plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I just want to do a simple correlation matrix plot. If I do:

```
library(GGally)
data(flea)
ggpairs(flea, columns = 2:4)
```

I get these strange numbers in the top triangle:
[image]

Why?

First, I installed the CRAN version, and it happened to me. Right now, I have the GitHub version, and the same thing happens to me.

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
```

Comment: Can you try this command: `ggpairs(flea, columns = 2:4, upper=list(continuous = "cor_v1_5")`? I think your problem is due to a missing font in your system but I haven't found which one yet.

Comment: Found it in the help file `?ggally_statistic`. The font family = "mono" is used for these parts of the pair plot.

Comment: So if your problem is really related to a missing font, then you should have the same issue with the command `plot(1:10, family = "mono")`. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes Vincent! I have the same problem with `r plot(1:10, family = "mono")`. However, `ggpairs(flea, columns = 2:4, upper=list(continuous = "cor_v1_5"))` works fine for me.
Do I need to install mono font in Ubuntu or R?

Comment: I think you need to install something like `xfonts`. Just out of curiosity: what happens when you save your plot in a pdf device with the command `pdf("testmono.pdf");plot(1:10, family = "mono");dev.off()` ?

Comment: It saves correctly. When I tried `sudo apt install xfonts-utils`, it says that it is already in the newest version

Comment: It has to be one of the xfonts packages